# Find the OS X kext library that contains a symbol

Tags: macos, kernel, darwin

with Snow Leopard 10.6.4 I am obtaining an unresolved symbol:

```
$ sudo kextutil KRPC.kext
(kernel) kxld[com.machackershandbook.kext.KRPC]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
(kernel) kxld[com.machackershandbook.kext.KRPC]: _mig_buckets
```

I cannot find this symbol using kextfind, however this symbol is exported in the kernel:

```
$ kextfind -dsym _mig_buckets
$ nm -arch i386 /mach_kernel |grep _mig_buckets
00844b00 S _mig_buckets
$ nm -arch x86_64 /mach_kernel |grep _mig_buckets
ffffff8000672e40 S _mig_buckets
```

How can I find the kext library to link with this symbol using the `OSBundleLibraries` dict?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running [`kextlibs`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/kextlibs.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/kextlibs) on your kext? it may give you the correct dependency.
Otherwise, it is likely one of the following:

- com.apple.kpi.mach
- com.apple.kpi.unsupported

see [this apple Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1575.html) for more information about the unsupported KPI

Comment: Thank you, in addition to com.apple.kpi.mach and com.apple.kpi.unsupported I have added most of the kexts.

Comment: I also used both methods that you propose and these methods share the same luck:

$ sudo kextlibs rpc_server.kext
For all architectures:
    com.apple.kpi.libkern = 10.4
For i386:
    2 symbols not found in any library kext.
$ /Developer/usr/bin/FindKPI.py _mig_buckets
_mig_buckets not found

Comment: There is something strange here because it seems that the symbol is actually exported in the kernel.

$ nm -arch i386 /mach_kernel |grep _mig_buckets
00844b00 S _mig_buckets

Comment: I think mig_buckets is no longer exported, probably part of this ( http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/Darwin/RN-KernelExtensions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001023-CH1-DontLinkElementID_11 )